# How to get a value in a string list?

Tags: android

I have a list containing the following:

```
String list[]={"Team 1,Apple,Mango,Kiwi","Team 2,Mango,Kiwi,Pineapple","Team 3,Kiwi,Pineapple,Apple"};
```

my question is, how do you know what each team has? also how do you get the team name?

i would like to have the output:

```
Team 1,Team 3(Apple,Kiwi)
Team 1,Team 2(Mango,Kiwi)
Team 2,Team 3(Pineapple,Kiwi)
```

can someone tell me what can be done or what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the values of the first string in a list of strings you can split the string by "," and put it in a list like following: `String s1 [] = list[0].split(",");` and then s1[0] is Team1 s1[1] is Apple etc..

Comment: splitting is one way. but how can i know if a particular fruit/s are on the team?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of StringTokenizer to accomplish your task.

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html
```